# Change code to expand blog entry on Shopify Couture theme (Django?)

Tags: blogs, liquid, shopify

Hi does anyone know how to update the code below so that blog 'excerpts' are fully expanded with full text and image/video removing the need to click through?

Thanks,

David

```
div id="blog" class="clearfix">
{% paginate blog.articles by settings.pagination_limit %}
<div class="more-info clearfix">
<span class="upper">{{ blog.title }}</span>
<span class="lower">{{ blog.articles_count }} {{ blog.articles_count | pluralize:      'Article', 'Articles' }}</span>
</div>

{% for article in blog.articles %}
<div class="article clearfix">
<div class="content">
  <h4><a href="{{ article.url }}">{{ article.title }}</a></h4>
  {{ article.content | strip_html | truncatewords:70 }}
</div>
</div> <!-- /.article -->
{% endfor %}
</div> <!-- /.main -->
{% include 'sidebar' %}
</div> <!-- /.articles -->

{% include 'pagination' %}
{% endpaginate %}
</div> <!-- /#blog -->
{% include 'featured-products' %}
```

Comment: I don't know what this is, but that's definitely not PHP.

Comment: Thanks I have just updated the tags to avoid any confusion…

Answer (score 0):

Aha! It’s written with Liquid (http://liquidmarkup.org/). The `truncatewords` [method](http://rubydoc.info/gems/liquid/2.3.0/Liquid/StandardFilters%3atruncatewords) takes the article’s content and shortens it to a maximum of 70 words. Removing that method call should fix the problem. There’s also a `strip_html` [method](http://rubydoc.info/gems/liquid/2.3.0/Liquid/StandardFilters%3astrip_html) that seems to remove any HTML from an article’s content. If there’s any HTML in the blog post that displays images or videos, this method may be to blame for removing them. This may fix your problem:

```
<div id="blog" class="clearfix">
{% paginate blog.articles by settings.pagination_limit %}
<div class="more-info clearfix">
<span class="upper">{{ blog.title }}</span>
<span class="lower">{{ blog.articles_count }} {{ blog.articles_count | pluralize:      'Article', 'Articles' }}</span>
</div>

{% for article in blog.articles %}
<div class="article clearfix">
<div class="content">
  <h4><a href="{{ article.url }}">{{ article.title }}</a></h4>
  {{ article.content }}
</div>
</div> <!-- /.article -->
{% endfor %}
</div> <!-- /.main -->
{% include 'sidebar' %}
</div> <!-- /.articles -->

{% include 'pagination' %}
{% endpaginate %}
</div> <!-- /#blog -->
{% include 'featured-products' %}
```

Comment: Apologies my skill set is only basic css / html. This has been taken from a shopify theme called Couture. And the file has a .liquid extension if that helps?

Comment: I have just realised now I have got the blog posts looking good, the next task will be to limit the amount of posts per page on the blog with previous entries link. I think this might be a bit more complex?